# Get data between two dates based on month and year in SqlLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date, date-arithmetic

I have a table set with a few columns of which my date of joining is a Date type column, I want to find all the employees who joined the organization between Jan 1980 to June 1985 [this could change based on incoming inputs],

If it was the entire date part we can directly put the dates in `BETWEEN` but not sure what to do in case of only month and year , using `strftime` will return string values that won't be idle for putting in a `BETWEEN`

Expected query

```
select * from table where dateA BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM' AND 'YYYY-MM'
```

What I have tried till

```
select * from table where (strftime('%Y', dateA) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1985') AND (strftime('%m', dateA) BETWEEN '01' AND '06')
```

But it is not returning the expected output

*Note: I be getting only Month and Year as input from the APIs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column's `dateA` format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and the dates that you get are in the format `YYYY-MM` then for the starting date you must concatenate `-01` and for the ending date use the function `date()` with modifiers that calculate the last day of the month:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE dateA BETWEEN 
            ?1 || '-01' 
            AND 
            date(?2 || '-01', '+1 month', '-1 day');
```

Replace `?1` and `?2` with your starting and ending dates in the format `YYYY-MM`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/r-z-C75B).